# Desktop: samsung syncmaster 933 drivers required

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display, lcd

Any idea where I can find Win XP drivers for Samsung syncmaster 933?

tried the samsung site but no joy.

Comment: why do you need drivers? Something special with this modeL? I haven't installed a display driver in ages...
(Also, this is superuser.com question).

Comment: Voted to move it to superuser; this site is more for sysadmin questions. It should automatically migrate there so you don't need to do anything (unless you need to link your account to the superuser sister site)

Comment: @svenW: yes, thats what i thought, but strangely, i dont get to choose the display modes for widescreen (native resolution)

Comment: This is an old question that was never answered.  Just to close the loop, the driver is available from Samsung here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/933BW.  However, it appears to be a generic VGA driver and should not be required for Win XP.